# node.js - Combining mysql results into a single object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So basically what I'm trying to do is something like this (not handling errors to make it shorter):

```
.get('/info', function(req, res){
    var combinedString = "";

    connection.query('SELECT col FROM table1 WHERE id = ?', [req.user.id], function(err, rows){
        combinedString += rows; 
    });

    connection.query('SELECT col FROM table2 WHERE id = ?', [req.user.id], function(err, rows){
        combinedString += rows; 
    });

    res.send(combinedString);
})
```

Now I understand that this is a problem due to node's async nature. Is there a way around it to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `connection.query` is async, `combinedString` is still empty at that time you `res.send`.

You'll need to `res.send` inside the callback function(s):

```
.get('/info', function(req, res){
    var combinedString = "";

    connection.query('SELECT col FROM table1 WHERE id = ?', [req.user.id], function(err, rows){
        combinedString += rows; 
        connection.query('SELECT col FROM table2 WHERE id = ?', [req.user.id], function(err, rows){
            combinedString += rows; 
            res.send(combinedString);
        });
    });

})
```